# 3S Lithium-Ion power solution for a project

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, discharge, bms, cell-balancing

I have a PCB that runs on **12V** throughout the day and consumes **2.3A**. The power is supplied for 12 hours using a power supply. The other 12 hours it must run on batteries that have charged during the first half of the day an so on and so forth.

So maybe we can use a pack of **3s9p Lithium-Ion** batteries with individual cell capacity of **3000mAH** as the required capacity is now **27AH**(2.3A x12 Hours) to supply the circuit for 12 hours.

Now the first question related to charging.

1-***Will a **3A** Lithium-Ion charger provide the necessary **27 Ah** capacity during charging in **12 hours**?***

Output current, 3A, constant current charging, the indicator light is red
Conversion current, 300mA, after full conversion, the indicator light is green

2- Using a 3S BMS with balance function and balance current of 45mA.

***Can I achieve proper balancing and charging using this BMS and the previous charger?***

Thanks in Advance

***A charger like this one:***

[image]

***BMS:***

[image]
[image]

Comment: The drawback I can see is that you're pushing the battery capacity hard, and that will shorten life to a few hundred cycles (a year if you are very lucky). Go for at least 50% over the required capacity, (say, 15p), charge to 4.1 or 4.15V not 4.2V, and don't discharge the pack fully. Then, even when the cells have lost 20% capacity (which will take much longer) they will still do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the capacity feedback. I will increase the capacity indeed. But I have no control over the max charge or discharge, only the BMS has. When external power is present the power will switch automatically.

Comment: Also I have another question. can this charger be used as a power supply for the project itself when the power is present? I mean will it supply the required current by the pcb(2.3A at my case) at 12.6v or does it act as a lithium ion charger only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 3s9p cells @ 3Ah /cell may supply 36Ah in 12h to a pack and with 27Ah capacity pack but additional soak time is required to achieve this capacity during CV mode. This is a tradeoff between battery life cycles and maximum capacity and may be defined in the charger design specs as 2 to 5% of CC rate with different CV thresholds from 4.1 to 4.2.  This additional time may take up to 20% or so. Overall power efficiency maybe 80% or so.

So this charger should charge in 12h but it is better not to let batteries reach 0% State of Charge (SoC) in order to get more Ah lifetime capacity.

A balanced current of 45mA/3A= 1.5% is reasonable to extend the life of batteries if they are matched <<1% as aggressive discharge times can increase mismatch tolerance.  Unless each voltage in the string is detected for Undervoltage (UV) cutoff in operation, the rate of discharge will accelerate the rate of a mismatch from the previous use. As the amount of time increases below UV and during CV, controls this ageing effect in addition to cell temperature.